Android Switching the call to speaker on button click
I am creating and android app that does an audio/video calls (like whatsapp). whenever a call is received/made, user can click a button to switch the voice from the low speaker to loud speaker.
On the onViewCreated() (I have the call in a fragment) function I check first if the call is a video or audio and toggle speakerphone accordingly.
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(!mAudioOnly);
mToggleSpeakerphoneBtn.setImageResource(mAudioOnly ? R.drawable.ic_volume_off : R.drawable.ic_volume_up); //Set icon to turn on/off speaker

Then I have an onclick listener for the button to toggle it back as follows:
mToggleSpeakerphoneBtn.setOnClickListener(v0 ->
     toggleSpeakerphone((FloatingActionButton) v0));

with toggleSpeakerphone as follows:
private void toggleSpeakerphone(FloatingActionButton b) {
    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) b.getContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    if (audioManager != null) {
        boolean enabled = audioManager.isSpeakerphoneOn();
        audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(!enabled);
        b.setImageResource(enabled ? R.drawable.ic_volume_off : R.drawable.ic_volume_up);
    }
}

The issue is here when I receive the audio call, voice is correctly coming from ear speaker. when I try to toggle loudspeaker the icon change as if loud speaker is active (which is never the case voice is always from the ear speaker) and for the remainder of the time trying to "deactivate" loudspeaker (which is already not running) fails as audioManager.isSpeakerphoneOn(); is always false.
What am I missing?
Manifest has the following permissions:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_OWN_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" /> 


well, you are missing a lot of stuff, e.g. Telecom Framework or setSpeakerphoneOn deprecation (currently doc saying that deprecated in API34+ but thats NOT true! it stopped working when setCommunicationDevice introduced, so API 31+)
if you are placing "official" call (assuming because of MANAGE_OWN_CALLS) then you are switching between earpiece/speaker through setAudioRoute (with value e.g CallAudioState.ROUTE_SPEAKER)
if you are not placing "official" call, just playing audio then you shouldn't be setting setMode and setSpeakerPhone (or setCommunicationDevice) should work
you may find some useful code in my related SO question in HERE

I can not make it working with phone call - to answer incoming call on speaker
